# On the Run Forms in HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a query regarding form generation based on current inputs, 
like in applications the text input appear based on our choice.

I am trying to make it work using JavaScript , but my code doesn't do anything:

```
                       <html>
                       <head>
                      <script>
                           function addInput() {
                                          if (fields != 10) {
                          document.getElementById('d_div').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' /><br />";
                                            fields += 1;
                                           } else {
                                            document.getElementById('d_div').innerHTML += "<br />Only 10 upload fields allowed.";
                                            document.form.add.disabled=true;
                                            }}
                     </script>
                </head>
                        <body>
                             <div align = "center">
                             <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                             Select a Template<br />
                             <select name = "template" id = "rawquery">
                             <option>Select</option>
                             <option value = "Alpha query">Alpha</option>
                             <option value = "Betaquery">Beta</option>
                             <option value = "Gamma query">Gamma</option>
                             <option value = "Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
                             </select>
                             <br/> 
                           <input type = "submit" name = "submit"><br /><br />
                       </form>
                    </div>
                              <textarea name = "raw" rows = "10" cols = "50" id = "Raw">raw template</textarea>
                              <br /><br />
                        <form id="d_form">
                       <input type="submit" onclick="addInput()" name="newform" value="Click to enter values">
                       </form>
                         <div id="d_div">  </div>
                         </div> 
                         <br> <br> <br> <br> 
                                 </body>
                                 </html>
```

The code making drop-down menu is not used here.

When I click on the button to enter values it doesn't give me a new text area; can you please help, I am very new to this and learning?

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is , based on the choice of drop down menu some new fileds will appear which will ask for a value .

Comment: Try this framework, it might help https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms

Comment: We've tried to tidy up your question, and format your code slightly more tidily, but your HTML seems to be invalid (particularly the `<input type "submit" t" name "submit" t"><br/><br/>`. You have to use the `attributeName="attributeValue"` form, the `=` sign is *not* optional. Also you have trailing, disconnected letters and quotes `"` in multiple elements. Please correct your HTML before being surprised that JavaScript doesn't work.

Comment: i have edited the code , with proper HTML formatting, can you please check it now if there are any basic errors you can find

Answer (score 0):

- where is 'fields'-initialization?
- don't forget returning false, if really don't need to submit form #d_form clicking button #newform

Comment: I have initialzed feilds to "0" , if i dont submit the "d_form" how do i call addinput() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems with your tags. First make those right. I am giving an example
of creating dynamic tags. I think you can use it.copy and see how it works

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
fields=0;

    function addInput() {
        textvalue=document.getElementById("raw").value;
        var opt = document.createElement("option");

        if (fields != 10) {
            opt.text=textvalue;
            document.getElementById('rawquery').options.add(opt);
            fields += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('d_div').innerHTML += "<br />Only 10 upload fields allowed.";
            document.form.add.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: HI Polin , thanks however this is not what i am looking for i am trying to create text inputs on the run , meaning based on the input from a drop down menu a form with input type text should appear , i have exclusively mentioned the <div> so i guess creating news ones is redundant

Comment: @Riddle I've changed my script use it instead your script. It works